# ADD Custom Claims in Azure ACS Assertions

Tags: security, azure, single-sign-on, acs, azure-acs

We have our on premise claims aware application registered as relying party with `Azure ACS`. we would like to send few claims to the application from a custom data store along with the claims from the `Azure AD`, how do we add a custom data store in `Azure ACS`?

Answer (score 0):

ACS can only transform claims from identity providers. Additional claims, including those from Azure AD's Graph API, needs to be handled at application level, e.g. through additional OWIN middlewares.